# Is order of variables important in php?

Tags: php

I have the following variables in my php test script :

```
$url="http://example.com";
$uri="/index.php";
$url="$url$uri";
echo $url;
```

This returns the values of 2 variables $url and $uri, and the result i get is :

```
  http://example.com/index.php
```

My question is : if php processes variables from top to bottom then ,why does "echo $url" not display the value of first variable "http://example.com" ?

And in this situation how will I be able to echo the value of first variable? Do I need to move the first variable from top to middle? :

```
$uri="/index.php";
$url="$url$uri";
$url="http://example.com";
echo $url;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes it's important..... if you use a variable before you assign a value to it, PHP will create that variable and define a value of null

Comment: The fact that you then overwrite the original value of $url with a new value means that is the new value that will be used subsequently (eg when you echo it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is order of variables important in php?

Order of statements is. PHP does things in the order you tell it to do them.

> if php processes variables from top to bottom then ,why does "echo $url" not display the value of first variable

It does. It's just that that variable no longer has the value you gave it on line 1 because you gave it a new value on line 3.

> And in this situation how will I be able to echo the value of first variable?

There are lots of approaches to that and …

> Do I need to move the first variable from top to middle?

… would do it, but makes the line `$url="$url$uri";` entirely pointless.

---

You need to step back and think about what you actually want to achieve.

If you need to keep the URL to the site root around *and* have the combined URL available somewhere, then maybe introducing a third variable name is the way forward.

If you are just debugging and want to make sure the value of `$url` is right before you change it, then you should probably move your `echo` statement instead.